# Best way to repeat a character in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

What is the best way to generate a string of `\t`'s in C#?

I am learning C# and experimenting with different ways of saying the same thing.

`Tabs(uint t)` is a function that returns a `string` with `t` amount of `\t`'s

For example, `Tabs(3)` returns `"\t\t\t"`

Which of these three ways of implementing `Tabs(uint numTabs)` is best?

Of course that depends on what "best" means.

1. The LINQ version is only two lines, which is nice.  But are the calls to Repeat and Aggregate unnecessarily time/resource consuming?
2. The `StringBuilder` version is very clear, but is the `StringBuilder` class somehow slower?
3. The `string` version is basic, which means it is easy to understand.
4. Does it not matter at all?  Are they all equal?

These are all questions to help me get a better feel for C#.

```
private string Tabs(uint numTabs)
{
    IEnumerable<string> tabs = Enumerable.Repeat("\t", (int) numTabs);
    return (numTabs > 0) ? tabs.Aggregate((sum, next) => sum + next) : "";
}

private string Tabs(uint numTabs)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (uint i = 0; i < numTabs; i++)
        sb.Append("\t");

    return sb.ToString();
}

private string Tabs(uint numTabs)
{
    string output = "";
    for (uint i = 0; i < numTabs; i++)
    {
        output += '\t';
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1889, accepted):

What about this:

```
string tabs = new string('\t', n);
```

Where `n` is the number of times you want to repeat the string.

Or better:

```
static string Tabs(int n)
{
    return new string('\t', n);
}
```

Comment: is there any way to repeat this for a word? instead of using '\t' how to use "time"

Comment: @user1478137 Or, better (also further down): [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15390726/2030691)

Comment: When replacing '\t' by a space (ie. " "), I find that on some laptops it is seen as a white space and on some others, a "return key" gets added after the spaces at the end of the line. The other answer suggested here below, that uses string.Concat, also behaves in the same weird way on some laptops. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 231):

```
string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("ab", 2));
```

Returns

> "abab"

And

```
string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("a", 2));
```

Returns

> "aa"

from...

[Is there a built-in function to repeat string or char in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115064/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-repeat-string-or-char-in-net)

Comment: Make it better by doing it without Linq and with `StruingBuilder`!

Comment: ''StringBuilder'' is not necessarily faster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585860/string-join-vs-stringbuilder-which-is-faster

Comment: It may not be faster, but it can save on memory allocations (pressure) if you specify the correct capacity up front, and that can be as important as the micro benchmark of profiling this.

Comment: var strRepeat = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("ABC", 1000000));  //50ms

Comment: How does that answer the question? It was *"What is the best way to generate a string of \t's in C#?"*. A question is more than the title. And about three specific methods for doing do.

Answer (score 152):

In all versions of .NET, you can repeat a string thus:

```
public static string Repeat(string value, int count)
{
    return new StringBuilder(value.Length * count).Insert(0, value, count).ToString();
}
```

To repeat a character, `new String('\t', count)` is your best bet. See [the answer by @CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/411762).

Comment: This is by far the fastest performance wise for String. Other methods create too much overhead.

Comment: @midspace Do you know if anybody has explained why the other answers are worse? I would have assumed the native String.Concat would be just as optimized internally as StringBuilder

Comment: @Marie The following article explains some of the merits. https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/306822/how-to-improve-string-concatenation-performance-in-visual-c
Otherwise two other factors are, StringBuilder allows strings and isn't limited to just a char (though that doesn't pertain to the original question), and the string.Concat answer above has to create an array first using Enumerable.Repeat. As I said, it's unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I had assumed it wouldnt create an array first because it could just iterate item by item. Thank you for the link, I will ggive it a read!

Answer (score 68):

The best version is certainly to use the builtin way:

```
string Tabs(int len) { return new string('\t', len); }
```

Of the other solutions, prefer the easiest; only if this is proving too slow, strive for a more efficient solution.

<del>If you use a `StringBuilder` and know its resulting length in advance, then also use an appropriate constructor, this is much more efficient because it means that only one time-consuming allocation takes place, and no unnecessary copying of data.</del>
Nonsense: of course the above code is more efficient.

Comment: My benchmarks are showing `new string('\t', len)` to be between 2x and 7x faster than the `StringBuilder` approach. Why do you think `StringBuilder` is more efficient in this case?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Thanks for correcting this (after it has been standing here for two years, no less!).

Answer (score 54):

Extension methods:

```
public static string Repeat(this string s, int n)
{
    return new String(Enumerable.Range(0, n).SelectMany(x => s).ToArray());
}

public static string Repeat(this char c, int n)
{
    return new String(c, n);
}
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, n).SelectMany(x => s)` can be replaced by a simple `Enumerable.Repeat(s, n)`.

Comment: @Palec No it cannot. The `SelectMany` will for each single dummy `x` give a sequence of `char` values (since the `string s` implements `IEnumerable<char>`), and all those `char` sequences are concatenated to one long `char` sequence. What you suggest will instead give an `IEnumerable<string>`. It is not the same.

Comment: I was wrong, @JeppeStigNielsen. Thanks for the heads-up. If I really wanted to use `Enumerable.Repeat`, I would have to concatenate the strings together: `string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(s, n))`. This has already been [posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15390726/2157640).

Answer (score 43):

Use an extension method:

---

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
   public static string Repeat(this char chatToRepeat, int repeat) {

       return new string(chatToRepeat, repeat);
   }

   public  static string Repeat(this string stringToRepeat, int repeat)
   {
       var builder = new StringBuilder(repeat*stringToRepeat.Length);
       for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
           builder.Append(stringToRepeat);
       }
       return builder.ToString();
   }
}
```

---

You could then write:

```
Debug.WriteLine('-'.Repeat(100)); // For Chars
Debug.WriteLine("Hello".Repeat(100)); // For Strings
```

Note that a performance test of using the StringBuilder version for simple characters instead of strings gives you a major performance penality:

On my computer the difference in measured performance is 1:20 between:

```
Debug.WriteLine('-'.Repeat(1000000)) // Char version
```

and

```
Debug.WriteLine("-".Repeat(1000000)) // String version
```

Comment: The performance of the string version may be improved by using [`StringBuilder.Insert(Int32, String, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62eb5xsf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as [Binoj Anthony answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/720915/2157640).

Comment: I used the code and that was good for me. But the other answers in this q are good too.

Answer (score 27):

Let's say you want to repeat '\t' n number of times, you can use;

```
String.Empty.PadRight(n,'\t')
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is also very fast. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36391/adding-n-characters-to-a-string

Comment: I have always done it this way. Even if wrapped in an extension method it is simpler than other implementations posted here. Note that OP did just want to repeat \t, not strings.

Answer (score 26):

There is a simple way to repeat a string that even works in .NET 2.0.

To repeat a string:

```
string repeated = new String('+', 3).Replace("+", "Hello, ");
```

Returns

> "Hello, Hello, Hello, "

To repeat a string as an array:

```
// Two line version.
string repeated = new String('+', 3).Replace("+", "Hello,");
string[] repeatedArray = repeated.Split(',');

// One line version.
string[] repeatedArray = new String('+', 3).Replace("+", "Hello,").Split(',');
```

Returns

> {"Hello", "Hello", "Hello", ""}

Keep it simple.

Comment: How does that answer the question? It was *"What is the best way to generate a string of \t's in C#?"*. A question is more than the title. And about three specific methods for doing do.

Answer (score 25):

How about this:

```
//Repeats a character specified number of times
public static string Repeat(char character,int numberOfIterations)
{
    return "".PadLeft(numberOfIterations, character);
}

//Call the Repeat method
Console.WriteLine(Repeat('\t',40));
```

Comment: haha.. that's what I could think of when I fell into this situation once. But personally I found `new string('\t', 10)` to be the best solution

Answer (score 19):

Your first example which uses `Enumerable.Repeat`:

```
private string Tabs(uint numTabs)
{
    IEnumerable<string> tabs = Enumerable.Repeat(
                                 "\t", (int) numTabs);
    return (numTabs > 0) ? 
            tabs.Aggregate((sum, next) => sum + next) : ""; 
}
```

can be rewritten more compactly with `String.Concat`:

```
private string Tabs(uint numTabs)
{       
    return String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("\t", (int) numTabs));
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Using `String.Concat` and `Enumerable.Repeat` which will be less expensive
than using `String.Join`

```
public static Repeat(this String pattern, int count)
{
    return String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(pattern, count));
}
```

Comment: Can you quantify that? On a particular system.

Answer (score 8):

```
var str = new string(Enumerable.Repeat('\t', numTabs).ToArray());
```

Comment: why additional enumerable when there's same result with: 

new string('\t', numTabs)

Answer (score 4):

The answer really depends on the complexity you want. For example, I want to outline all my indents with a vertical bar, so my indent string is determined as follows:

```
return new string(Enumerable.Range(0, indentSize*indent).Select(
  n => n%4 == 0 ? '|' : ' ').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

And yet another method

```
new System.Text.StringBuilder().Append('\t', 100).ToString()
```

Comment: Passing the resulting string length to `StringBuilder` constructor saves reallocation. Still, this is more chatty and less efficient than using the `string` constructor that can repeat a given character, as already shown in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an extension method

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    internal static string Repeat(this char c, int n)
    {
        return new string(c, n);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
Console.WriteLine('\t'.Repeat(10));
```

Answer (score 4):

For me this is fine:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static string LeftZerosFormatter(int zeros, int val)
    {
        string valstr = val.ToString();

        valstr = new string('0', zeros) + valstr;

        return valstr.Substring(valstr.Length - zeros, zeros);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fine in what way?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Add leading zeros to a number? How does that answer the question? It was *"What is the best way to generate a string of \t's in C#?"*. And about three specific methods for doing do.

Answer (score 1):

Without a doubt the accepted answer is the best and fastest way to repeat a single character.

Binoj Anthony's answer is a simple and quite efficient way to repeat a string.

However, if you don't mind a little more code, you can use my array fill technique to efficiently create these strings even faster.  In my comparison tests, the code below executed in about 35% of the time of the StringBuilder.Insert code.

```
public static string Repeat(this string value, int count)
{
    var values = new char[count * value.Length];
    values.Fill(value.ToCharArray());
    return new string(values);
}

public static void Fill<T>(this T[] destinationArray, params T[] value)
{
    if (destinationArray == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("destinationArray");
    }

    if (value.Length > destinationArray.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Length of value array must not be more than length of destination");
    }

    // set the initial array value
    Array.Copy(value, destinationArray, value.Length);

    int copyLength, nextCopyLength;

    for (copyLength = value.Length; (nextCopyLength = copyLength << 1) < destinationArray.Length; copyLength = nextCopyLength)
    {
        Array.Copy(destinationArray, 0, destinationArray, copyLength, copyLength);
    }

    Array.Copy(destinationArray, 0, destinationArray, copyLength, destinationArray.Length - copyLength);
}
```

For more about this array fill technique, see [Fastest way to fill an array with a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943850/fastest-way-to-fill-an-array-with-a-single-value/22867582#22867582)

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "abc"
string output = "";
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    output += input[i].ToString() + input[i].ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

```
=aabbcc
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? It was *"What is the best way to generate a string of \t's in C#?"*. A question is more than the title. And about three specific methods for doing do.

Answer (score -1):

Albeit very similar to a previous suggestion, I like to keep it simple and apply the following:

```
string MyFancyString = "*";
int strLength = 50;
System.Console.WriteLine(MyFancyString.PadRight(strLength, "*");
```

It is standard .NET, really.

Comment: It will just add padding, does not repeat

Comment: @levi: What is the problem with padding? Does `string result = string.Empty.PadRight('\t',5)` not return the desired result (in this case, 5 tabs)?

Comment: How does that answer the question? It was *"What is the best way to generate a string of \t's in C#?"*. A question is more than the title. And about three specific methods for doing do.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

1. Add the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` reference
2. Use: `String result = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.StrDup(5, "hi");`

Comment: Adding dependence on another assembly and the need to load it is unreasonable in most cases when you need such functionality. Still, good to know there is such a thing in .NET.

Comment: There many pros and cons in different contexts, so everyone should decide depending on the situation she/he is in.

Comment: How does that answer the question? It was *"What is the best way to generate a string of \t's in C#?"*. A question is more than the title. And about three specific methods for doing do.

Answer (score -2):

Fill the screen with 6,435 z's:

```
$str = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Repeat([string]::new("z", 143), 45)

$str
```

Comment: What is this? [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)? That is hardly C#.

Comment: How does that answer the question? It was *"What is the best way to generate a string of \t's in C#?"*. A question is more than the title. And about three specific methods for doing do.