# Making a bunch of Comma

Tags: c#, string, linq, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to repeat a character in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp)

I'm making a big Comma separated CSV file. Most of the files fields are null and it would be provided later on, so I need to insert just a comma. I made a simple method:

```
 private string MakeComma(int CommaNumber)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
    for (int i = 0; i < CommaNumber; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(",");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way using Linq, Join etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
new string(',', 42);
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa331867%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)