# How to display a number with a given number of decimal places

Tags: c#, string, iteration

I write function about add 0 for use to add decimal place in string format like this

```
   Function String DtoS_ (decimal value ,int decimalplace)
   {
     decimal result = value;
     String format = ""#,##0";
     if(decimalplace> 0)
     {
       format += ".";
       for( int i =0;i<decimalplace;i++)
       {
         format +="0"; 
       }
     }  

     return result.ToString(format); //e.g. "#,##0.00"
   }
```

I want to know that is there other ways/trick to iteration that don't need to use for loop or while loop above , Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to know that is there other ways you could rephrase your question/problem. But AFAI understand, you could try going with Linq.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp

Comment: Please see duplicate or read [MSDN: Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#FFormatString). Decimal format strings can be followed by a number specifying the required number of decimals, like `-29541.ToString("F3")` yields `-29541.000`. You can pass your `decimalplace` into the format string. Use `N` instead of `F` to display thousand separators.

Comment: Sorry about my poor English writing skill.
"new string('0', decimalPlaces);" is exactly what I looking for(not Decimal format),but I don't know keyword to search so I asked the question by write that function as example. 
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this

```
decimal d = 1m;
int decimalPlaces = 2;
string format = decimalPlaces == 0 
            ? "#,##" 
            : "#,##." + new string('0', decimalPlaces);
string result = d.ToString(format); // 1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new string with the number of zeros you need as follows:

```
   // your existing code
   // replace the for with this approach
   temp = new String('0', decimalplace);
   format = "." + temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you are looking for:

```
    private static string DtoS2(decimal value, int decimalPlaces )
    {
        var format = decimalPlaces>0 ? "#,##0." + new string('0', decimalPlaces) : "#,##0";
        var result = value.ToString(format);
        return result;
    }
```

What it does is to create the format string depending on the decimal places.

At the end, you were very close. Instead of the loop, the `new string('0', decimalPlaces)` does exactly what you were looking for.