# 1000 same chars without using loops and repeating this char in code more than once

Tags: c#

Let's say we need to output 1000 # symbols in one line without loops or recursion. And surely without making a line of code with 1000 chars there.

The noob solution that comes to mind is...

```
string s = "#";
s = s+s+s+s+s+s+s+s+s+s;
s = s+s+s+s+s+s+s+s+s+s;
s = s+s+s+s+s+s+s+s+s+s;
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Are there any others?

Comment: Why you avoid the loop or recursion? And what kind of loop or recursion that you avoid? Is Linq including this restriction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to repeat a character in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I think he said that he avoid loop or recursion.

Comment: Why avoid? Just to make an exercise like this. ;)

Comment: Maybe it's his assignment or something. Idk.

Answer (score 7):

`var repeatedString = new string('#', 1000);`

Comment: Isn't that a kind of a loop anyways?

Comment: That's why I asked, "what kind of loop that he avoid". But it's much better than his "simplest solution" :)

Comment: Well I am no IL expert but it's not translated to a loop when I investigated the IL, you can argue that it is but I will stay away from that discussion :).  Also, using + for a string concatenation is not good for performance as strings are immutable (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306822)

Comment: Well, I asked this question more for fun and also to learn something. Thank you for your answer.