# Fill Line with hyphens

Tags: c#, label, line

i'm trying to fill one line of my label with hyphens. Here's what i got right now. what is the function that i can use to fill the next line without manually typing out all the hyphens?

```
lblResumé.Text = intNbrTotTut.ToString() + str1erePhrase + Environment.NewLine
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to repeat a character in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp)

Comment: didnt really work in my situation.

Comment: Why doesn't the linked post _"work in your situation?"_ You'll need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string myString = "Test" + Environment.NewLine + "Test2" +Environment.NewLine;
label1.Text = myString.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "_");
```