# How do I print # in a nested for loop

Tags: c#

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
 {
     string[] doors = new string[6];
     doors[i] = "#";
     for (int j = 1; j <=i; j++)
         {
            Console.Write(doors[j]); 
         }
     Console.Writeline():
}
```

Hi guys. I need to print # one and then # twice, until i get to six times. It says System.index.out.of.range. How come?

Comment: You don't want any *array* - `string[] doors` - at all. Just print out `#` - `Console.Write('#')`

Comment: How to i declare the # then?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2hEdV7

Comment: see the above example

Comment: @Kobus: you don't want to *declare* anything. Just print out a *constant* `#` in the loops: `Console.Write('#');`

Comment: Console.write('#') works. Thank you.

Comment: How do I click to accept this answer in the cooments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

> > I need to *print* **#** one and then **#** twice, until i get to six times.

You don't want any *array* - `string[] doors = new string[6];`, just loops:

```
for (int line = 1; line <= 6; ++line) {
  for (int column = 1; column <= line; ++column) {
    Console.Write('#'); 
  }

  Console.WriteLine(); 
}
```

If you have to work with array (i.e. array will be used somewhere else), get rid of magic numbers:

```
// Create and fill the array
string[] doors = new string[6];

for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++) 
  doors[i] = "#";

// Printing out the array in the desired view
for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    Console.Write(doors[j]); 
  } 

  Console.Writeline(); 
}
```

Please, notice that arrays are *zero-based* (array with `6` items has `0..5` indexes for them)

Answer (score 2):

You should try to extend your array, it's limited to 6 elements but you try to access 7 elements as you go through 0 to 6.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
 {
     string[] doors = new string[7];
     doors[i] = "#";
     for (int j = 1; j <=i; j++)
         {
            Console.Write(doors[j]); 
         }
     Console.Writeline():
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because it is out of range.

change it to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
 {
     string[] doors = new string[6];
     doors[i] = "#";
     for (int j = 0; j <=i.length; j++)
         {
            Console.Write(doors[j]); 
         }
     Console.Writeline():
}
```

Comment: What are you wanting `i.length` to do here? Given i is an `int` the answer to what it *actually* is doing is probably throwing a compiler error...

Answer (score 1):

No need to use 2 loops. Just [*repeat* that character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp)

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
{
  Console.Write(new String("#",i)); 
  Console.WriteLine():
}
```