# What is the shortest way of repeating a character n times in the middle of a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, ascii

I am currently Creating a ASCII table builder which is required for some automated database reports in a GXP environment.

Given that I have table rows with a width of n such as:

```
| this | is | an | example | row |
|<--       width = 32         -->|
```

I now want to add headers and spacers such as:

```
#================================#
| this | is | an | example | row |
|--------------------------------|
| 1    | 2  | 3  | 4       | 5   |
| 3    | 9  | 77 | 327814  | 2   |
|--------------------------------|
```

of course I could do this in the following way:

```
List<string> asciiTable = new List<string();
string topBorder = "#";
string otherBorder = "|";
for (int i = 1; i == n; i++)
{
    topBorder += "=";
    otherBorder += "-";
}
topBorder += "#";
otherBorder += "|";
asciiTable.Add(topBorder);
```

but I hope there is something such as:

```
List<string> asciiTable = new List<string>();
asciiTable.Add("#" + /* add("=",n) */ + "#");
```

Comment: `new string('z',234324)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to repeat a character in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `new String('=', n);` which will create a `string` with the character '=' repeated n times.