# String interpolation - repeat

Tags: c#, string, interpolation, string-interpolation

Is there any way to interpolate variable several times without repeating?

For example:

```
var name = "bla";
Console.WriteLine($"foo {name:repeat:2} bar")
```

to print

```
foo blabla bar
```

I'm particularly interested in interpolating several **line breaks** instead of repeating `{Environment.NewLine}` several times in the interpolation mask like this:

```
$"{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}"
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at this. Maybe combine with String.Format
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public static string Repeat(this string s, int times, string separator = "")
{
    return string.Join(separator, Enumerable.Repeat(s, times));
}
```

Then use:

```
Console.WriteLine($"foo {name.Repeat(2)} bar")
```

Comment: I thought it could have been some out-of-the-box option for string interpolation. But if not your solution looks like the simplest alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension method for the string type, thats repeating its input. Then simply use this method within the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
var name = "bla";
Console.WriteLine("foo {0}{0} bar", name);
// or
var s = String.Format("foo {0}{0} bar", name);
```

It will help you not repeating the same string, just index of it.

More about [String Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting)