# How to add space before string with loop C#

Tags: c#

How can I add space before a string with loop? Something like this:

```
string someString = "a";
for (int i = 0; i<5 ; i++)
{
   //add space before string code
}
```

Here is the logic I want:

```
//   int i = 0;
//   a;

//   int i = 1;
//   "\t" + a;

//   int i = 2;
//   "\t\t" + a;
```

Comment: is this a school assignment, in which you are required to use a loop? there are easier ways to achieve this (like string.PadLeft) actually

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to repeat a character in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp)

Comment: no it does not have to use loop what is the easiest way of doing it? @VT Chiew

Comment: Do you want spaces or tabs? Becuase in the 'logic you want' the char `\t` is a tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_) the string constructor:

```
int i = 5;
string result = new string('\t', i) + someString;
```

Since `string` is a immutable type, you create a new string each iteration which is pretty expensive. Because of that I would avoid the loop approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
string spaceString = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  spaceString += " ";
}

someString = spaceString + someString;
```

Comment: Is `string.Empty` a method?

Comment: @bolkay he made a mistake, the correct form is: `string spaceString = string.Empty;`

Answer (score 0):

you can use string format like that:

```
string tab = "";
string someString = a;
for (int i = 0; i<5 ; i++)
{
   //add space before string code
   tab += "\t";
   string.Format("{0}{1}", tab, someString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string somestring = a;
    for (int i = 0; i<5 ; i++)
    {
       string result = "";
       for(int j = 0; j<i ; j++)
       {
         result+= "\t";
       }
       result+= somestring;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string someString = "a";
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    result = new string('\t', i) + someString;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

As john indicated in the comment that you do not need to use a loop, this is the ideal way:

```
int i = 5;
string s = "x";

string result = s.PadLeft(i + s.Length,'\t');
```